# iOS App Store publishing under different account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, provisioning-profile

I'm pretty new to iOS development and it's not clear to me how to publish applications developed for customers. 
They want to release it under their name, and I don't want to provide them the source code, only the binaries. Do I have to log in with their account and upload it via Xcode/Application Loader or can it be done without accessing their account?

If I send them a Release Build, can they upload it under their account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need a developer account, you can either login with their account using Application Loader or in Xcode refresh the Provisioning Profiles `Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles` by typing in their `Apple-ID` and `password`. This load/reloads their Provisioning Profiles. You need a `valid App Store Profile` for your application to code sign it. `Archive` your app using Xcode and upload it to Apple by clicking `Distribute` on your `Archive` and `Upload` to the AppStore, type in the same credentials you used to download the profiles and you are done.
Hope that helps.

You can send them the Release Build but, you have to sign it with their Profiles so you need their PrivateKey, Developer profile and App Store Distributing Profile.

Comment: How to perform the same thing w/o customer's password but with admin's role in developer and itunesconnect portals?

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in with their account to upload it via the Application Loader.